# building a dynamic UI in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How hard is it to create a UI, which views is based on the data that a user has?
So say I can have a scroll view, and a particular user A can have a view which consists of X,Y,Z and user B can have a view which consists or Y, Z? I am just concerned about positioning the views in a views because we can't do that now via interface builder and it needs to be coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do a callback-based approach like UITableView, i.e. -cellForRowAtIndexPath, or a more explicit setter like UIMenu where you set the items.

For the latter approach, have a -setObjectsArray: or similar method where you configure your subviews according to the input data, i.e., make sure you have three of them if you have (x,y,z) and set their data to 0th view = x, 1st view = y, etc.

Next override -layoutSubviews and set the frames of each of the views based on their position in the order and your bounds.

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You can build an entire app with multiple views and controls without touching Interface Builder.  The UI views and elements can all be allocated and configured programmatically.

Apple even has a WWDC 2010 video on how to build data driven app UIs.

Comment: where is this? I can't find it on WWDC 2010 page on itunes

Comment: Log in to developer.apple.com and look for development videos

Comment: Is there any example on how to do this? It is only said "Do it this way, it's great!" but other than showing a plist example there is no explanation of how to implement this right.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is looking for Data Driven UI information the WWDC post from WWDC2010 is at about 40-41minutes in the Game development video part 1 (Video 401).

Other than that there is not a lot of information on data driven UI for Objective-C. I am about to add it to an existing project because we need multiple layouts for the same screen and i found it hard to just switch the view based on the layout (wrecked the bindings from memory).

Shouldn't be too hard though, simple framework to load the plist and use KVC to set all the values.

If people are new to KVC i would recommend adding the following method to stop errors happening when you set keys that don't exist, esp. if non-programmers are going to do some of the layout.

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSLog(@"The key %@ does not exist.", key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: It's session # 117: "Building a Server-Driven User Experience"

You can find it through iTunesU:

1. Search for WWDC2010
2. Go to "Application Frameworks"
3. Get "Session 117 - Building a Server-Driven User Experience"

The link to the PDF slides is on the page: [WWDC 2010 Session Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=117)

Ray